# Como pregunto si un textbox contiene información para poder hacer otra acción?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, vb.net

Tengo 4 `Textbox` donde cada uno tiene su respectiva información que son nombre, sección y teléfono y un botón para agregar dicha información a una base de datos `SQl`. Como pregunto si el `Textbox` tiene información entonces que se agreguen los datos y si no que me diga en un label o `msgbox` que agregue los datos. O sea que si no hay información en los `Textbox` no se agregue nada ya que el en `textbox1` va un numero que identifica a cada persona.

Este código es el del botón de agregar

```
    If TextBox1.Text <> Nothing And TextBox3.Text <> Nothing And TextBox4.Text <> Nothing Then
        Insertar()

    Else

        If (TextBox2.Text = String.Empty) And (TextBox3.Text = String.Empty) And (TextBox4.Text = String.Empty) Then
            
            Label6.Visible = True
        End If
    End If
```

Y ESTE ES EL PUBLIC SUB DE INSERTAR

```
    casilleros = Form3.TextBox1.Text
    nombre = Form3.TextBox2.Text
    seccion = Form3.TextBox3.Text
    telefono = Form3.TextBox4.Text
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = conx
    sql = "INSERT INTO Tabl"
    sql = "INSERT INTO Table_1(casilleros, nombre, seccion, telefono)"
    sql += " VALUES(" & casilleros & ", '" & nombre & "','" & seccion & "','" & telefono & "')"
    cmd.CommandText = sql
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("SE AGREGO CORRECTAMENTE")
        Form3.TextBox1.Text = ""
        Form3.TextBox2.Text = ""
        Form3.TextBox3.Text = ""
        Form3.TextBox4.Text = ""
        Dim frmCasilleros As New Form4
        frmCasilleros.Show()
        Form3.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("NO SE PUDO AGREGAR, INTENTE DE NUEVO")
        Form3.TextBox1.Text = ""
        Form3.TextBox2.Text = ""
        Form3.TextBox3.Text = ""
        Form3.TextBox4.Text = ""

    End Try
```

Si alguien me podría ayudar seria genial.... Gracias.

Comment: tenes que hacer un if en tus variables y preguntas si es null o empty ej if nombre == "" o si VB te lo permite if string.IsNullOrEmpty(nombre) then "Tu mensaje", hace mucho que no hago VB, espero que entiendas el ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

El valor `nothing` significa que algo no existe. En tu caso los `TextBox` si existen, pero su contenido puede estar vacío, que en VB.Net es una cadena vacía. Por lo que si arreglamos el primer IF lo solucionas.

```
If TextBox1.Text <> "" And TextBox3.Text <> "" And TextBox4.Text <> " Then
    Insertar()
Else
    Label6.Visible = True
End If
```

Pero puedes encontrarte con problemas, por ejemplo que un `TextBox` contenga un espacio en blanco, por ello es mejor hacer un `TRIM` de su contenido para hacer la comparación.

```
If Trim(TextBox1.Text) <> "" And Trim(TextBox3.Text) <> "" And Trim(TextBox4.Text) <> " Then
    Insertar()
Else
    Label6.Visible = True
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo hago esto, individualmente para controlar qué control tiene no no información:

```
If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Ingrese el Nombre", "Faltan Datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        TextBox1.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If 

If TextBox2.Text = Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Ingrese la sección", "Faltan Datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            TextBox2.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If 

'Repetir para cada control
Insertar()
```

Y así para cada control que deseo validar.